# "object reference not set to an instance of object" after saving changes in "Coded UI Test" Editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automation, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I want to change a property in "Coded UI Test" Editor (e.g. the mail value of some action in the list), but when I save the changes a message appears:

> "object reference not set to an instance of object"

and prevent saving the changes.

It hasn't happened to me before.

How can I force the changes to be saved?

Comment: Sounds like some object is not yet initialized. Hard to say more without some sample code. Can you add some code snippets?

Comment: @Sensei76 -  In the code - I can easily change. The problem is about changing in the `UIMap.uitest`. Will a screenshot be helpfull?